# SQL join duplicate my Data

Tags: sql, duplicates

I try to join some Tables but have an issue with duplicating Data

this is the code:

```
  select distinct
     VB1ACC.AcctCode
    ,VB1ACC.AcctName
    ,VPKA.Projektnummer as Project
    ,VPKA.Cost
   ,VPKA.Revenue
   ,VJZ.TransID

  from
ViewB1Accounts as VB1ACC


left join
   ViewProjektPlanungKontenAktuell as VPKA
 on
   VB1ACC.AcctCode = VPKA.AcctCode

 left join
  ViewJeZeilen as VJZ
 ON
VB1ACC.AcctCode = VJZ.ShortName
and
 VPKA.Projektnummer = VJZ.Project

where
  VPKA.Planungsversionstyp = 3
and
 VB1ACC.AcctCode between '3210' and '3250'
or
 VPKA.Planungsversionstyp = 3
and
 VB1ACC.AcctCode between '8210' and '8250'
```

When I now add the VJZ.TransID it is starting to duplicate my rows as the 
"Projektnummer" is more than once there.

The Goal is now to remove the duplication.

Any Idea?

Update:
[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdUTB.png)

as you can see in the record is there 23 times for acct Code 3212.
The reason I is tehe field Trans ID. In the next picture you have different trans ID according to the same project and acctcode.

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd3jP.png)

How can I prevent now the duplicating?

Comment: With duplicating do you mean the rows you ment to group are showing up multiple times? And those all have 1 value that is different? If so you have a wrong join

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: If you get duplication, on of your joins is a one-to-many relationship. In that case you'll have to find a way to make that a one-to-one relationship. The method depends on your data. Also, consider adding parentheses in your `where` clause; mixing `and` and `or` without parentheses seldom gives the expected result (unless you know the rules really well).

Answer (score 0):

use group by

> group by VB1ACC.AcctCode
>        ,VB1ACC.AcctName
>        ,VPKA.Projektnummer as Project
>        ,VPKA.Cost    ,VPKA.Revenue    ,VJZ.TransID